# return rows postgresql using node.js and hapi

Tags: node.js, postgresql, hapi.js

I run select query using pg ,node.js and hapi, and its work.
***but how can i return the rows?***

The selected:

```
 var client = new pg.Client(conString);
        client.connect(function(err,done) {

            if (err) {
                return console.error('could not connect to postgres', err);
            }
        })


function fun(query){
 client.query(query, function (err, result,done) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('error running query', err);
                    return;
                }
                else{

                    result.rowAsArray=true;
                    console.log(result.rows[0]);
                    data=result.rows;
            }

            });
            return data

        }
}
```

but its return a object with nothing,
What is the right way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the result set.

```
function fun(query) {
  var data = [];

  var sql = client.query(query, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.error('error running query', err);
      return;
    }
  });

  sql.on('row', function(row) {
    console.log(row);
    data.push(row);
  }

  return data;
}
```

Comment: i get this error: **TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'**. what can i do?

Comment: I corrected the answer. The `on row` event handler should have been outside of the query function. But, in fact your approach was good. You should be able to assign `data=result.rows` and then return `data`. What is the value of `result.rowCount`?

Comment: The error now is: **TypeError: Uncaught error: Object  select * from sponsors has no method 'on'**  where does on() come from?

Comment: The value of rowCount is 8

Comment: Try now, the name of the variable was conflicting with the name of the function argument - `query`.

Comment: yes it works, but how do I call this function as part of a synchronous process?

Comment: i did this but array conent is noting!